# logstash - how to convert date represented as String to a different format as a Date data type

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a need to convert a string to a Date value in the grok filter of my logstash.conf file. I have used the mutate plugin for converting ints to float like this:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        convert => {"sequence" => "float"}
    }
}
```

, however I don't see a way to do this with string version of a date to a DATE data type.

I received a suggestion to use the date filter plugin for my needs. The problem is that the date filter parses the input values properly but cannot convert the input format to another format.

I found a post where you first parse with date filter, and then use the date_formatter plugin to change the format. This had great potential except that date_formatter plugin is not available to me.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are several things `mutate` can't mutate.  Use the [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filter.

Comment: Hi, yes. I can use the date filter to parse the date, sent to a new target, but not to convert it.Date does not convert. I found a date_formatter plugin that does, but I cannot install that plugin in my environment.

Comment: just to be clear, Date filter cannot be used by itself to convert from string formatA to string formatB. It has no conversion options so above suggestion is not correct. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy I didn't suggest using the date filter to convert one string to another, because the original request was to convert it to a date, which is exactly what the date filter does.